Single Switch with Momentary and Latching/Hold Properties Using CMOS/Logic (no µP/microprocessor)
I am looking for a CMOS/logic based solution (no µP/microprocessor) to a momentary switching scheme I'd like to implement that involves the following scenario:
1: pressing a momentary switch engages or bypasses the circuit. We can call this circuit A.
2: holding the momentary switch for a set time switches circuit A to another circuit (a hold somewhere in the 2-3 seconds range, doesn't have to be exact, just enough to differentiate between a quick press and a deliberate hold). We can call this circuit B.
3: while using circuit B you should be able to press (not hold) the momentary switch as you see fit without it engaging or bypassing the overall circuit, but instead the momentary switch is used to turn an LED on and off, or send a pulse, for example.
4: while in circuit B, holding the momentary switch again for a set time switches circuit B back to circuit A, allowing you to engage or bypass the overall circuit with a press of the momentary switch as in the beginning.
Essentially, I'm looking for a way to use a momentary switch in both a momentary and latching configuration for a 2-in-1 type circuit configuration, where  momentary presses turn the circuit on and off, holding the switch changes to another circuit where you can use the momentary switch as you see fit (but not turn everything on/off), and holding again returns you back to the first circuit where you can press to turn on and off.
I've looked around and found several circuits that seem to come close (here and elsewhere), and perhaps it's the nature of trying to search for this idea using a multitude of different terms for essentially the same thing that has led me to not yet find a suitable solution. A circuit that seems to come close, in principle, is the Press ON - Hold OFF Latching Circuit shown here.
Supply voltage can be anywhere between 5-12V, ideally 5-9V (unipolar/single side supply, so 5-12V/0V), so no need for higher supply voltage concerns. I know this would be a relatively simple thing to accomplish with a few lines of code, but I would love to be able to figure this out logically, so to speak.

EDIT
Here is a quick sketch of what I had in mine:

The "Press ON - Hold OFF Latching Circuit" I posted toward the bottom of my initial question is pretty close to what I had in mind, but not quite. I had not considered a mono-flop, and I am admittedly a bit unfamiliar with their workings.

Welcome to SE/EE! You took the [tour], which is good, many newcomers do not. Your question has a lot of information, however, a schematic with the required logic as a black box will make it better. Would you mind to add one, please? Additionally, what have you seen and rejected, why, and what have you tried? Did you consider to use a mono-flop to distinguish between short and long actions, and tried to come up with a logic?

@thebusybee here is a link to a quick sketch of what I had in mine: link hopefully that formatted correctly (can only posts links in replies insofar as I can see). The "Press ON - Hold OFF Latching Circuit" I posted toward the bottom of my initial question is pretty close to what I had in mind, but not quite.  I had not considered a mono-flop, and I am admittedly a bit unfamiliar with their workings.

Well, you can post links, and images. However, images are limited in size, of course. And questions should be self-contained, because external resources tend to vanish, which makes such a link useless. You might need to put some effort in your question, but this is right because you expect the same from our answers. -- I copied your comment's content in the question.

@thebusybee thank you, and my apologies - I'm still getting used to this platform, and I noticed that after a couple/few minutes I couldn't edit comments, and I erroneously thought that also applied to questions as well!
